# Hide/show Button at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile-6

I need your help with c# and some graphic issues: I'm developing a very simple application. There is a unique form called DeltaPregView, a controller for the form called DeltaPregController and a class that contains the Main of the project:

Main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace deltaPreg
{
    static class Program
    {
        [MTAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //create the view
            DeltaPregView view = new DeltaPregView();
            //link the view to the APP
            Application.Run(view);
            //initialize the controller of the APP
            DeltaPregController controller = new DeltaPregController(view);
        }
    }
}
```

View for the class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace deltaPreg
{
    public partial class DeltaPregView : Form
    {
        public DeltaPregView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void init()
        {
            prova.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

and the Controller for the view:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace deltaPreg
{
    class DeltaPregController
    {
        #region variables
        private DeltaPregView view;
        #endregion

        public DeltaPregController(DeltaPregView view)
        {
            this.view = view;
            //start the reading process
            start();
        }
        private void start()
        {
            view.init();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to hide the button called "prova", but nothing changes in my program. I'm a newbie in the winforms management, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you print the form before you call the `init` function in `DeltaPregView`.

One way to solve this is by replacing those lines:

```
    //link the view to the APP
    Application.Run(view);
    //initialize the controller of the APP
    DeltaPregController controller = new DeltaPregController(view);
```

To:

```
    //initialize the controller of the APP
    DeltaPregController controller = new DeltaPregController(view);
    //link the view to the APP
    Application.Run(view);
```

Comment: Ok, it works this way...Mmh...but this means that I can't modify the form at runtime? I mean: how can I modify the form once it is created and make the changes visible? Do I have to reprint the form in some way?

Comment: @superpuccio You can change it at runtime without reprinting, but make sure it happens AFTER `Application.Run(view);` has been called.
You changed the property of the button before it was actually exist.